# what is a good learning path for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I suppose, I am having good programming experience in Java. I spent previous 5 yrs in test automation using Selenium, TestNG, Cucumber, Git and Maven. Now I want to learn more about CI/CD paradigm by integrating in to Jenkins pipeline. I searched in Amazon and Udemy for learning resources. There are **too many options**. Like *Jenkins combined with Docker, DevOps, AWS*.

My questions are ...

1. What are the trends in Jenkins integration with respect to regular Java Development, and with new technology like microservices, spring boot etc.,
2. What are the new upcoming patterns with AWS, Kubernetes, Docker etc.,
3. What should be my first steps in leaning around Jenkins ?

Comment: We don't offer study or learning advice (or any other sort of advice). We also don't discuss *upcoming patterns* or *future plans* of off-site projects or products. Do you have any specific questions related to programming (code) or **use of** a programmers tool? You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time reviewing the [help] pages, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question as a blog post on medium website. It lays step by step approach consisting of 10 steps. Some of the steps are [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) courses and some other are web site urls. Please access the article at 
[Top Tutorials To Learn Jenkins CI For Testing Automation](https://medium.com/quick-code/top-tutorials-to-learn-jenkins-ci-for-testing-automation-93c7ac068f66)